# Navbar items jumping to a new line inside a grid item container on md breakpoint

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, grid, next.js

I only have the following problem on md breakpoint, the rest works find wether its a larger breakpoint or smaller.

[image]

I want it to be like this:

[image]

that is the links and icons be on the same line.

Code:

```js
<Grid
    container
    direction="row"
    justify="space-between"
    alignItems="center"
    spacing={10}
>
    <Grid item container xs={4} justify="flex-start">
        <Logo/>
        <CategoryBtn />
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={4}>
        <Search />
    </Grid>
    <Grid item container xs={4} justify="flex-end" >
        <Grid item>
            <ShoppingCartBtn />
            <LanguageBtn />
            <DarkModeBtn />
            <NotificationBtn />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
            {signedIn? <SignedIn /> : <SignedOutLinks />}
        </Grid>
     </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, finally found the answer myself. just use the property wrap="nowrap"

```
            <Grid
                container
                direction="row"
                justify="space-between"
                alignItems="center"
                spacing={10}
            >
              <Grid item container spacing={10} xs={4} justify="flex-start" wrap="nowrap">
                <Grid item>
                  <Logo/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item>
                  <CategoryBtn />
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={4}>
                <Search />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item container xs={4} justify="flex-end" wrap="nowrap">
                  <ShoppingCartBtn />
                  <LanguageBtn />
                  <DarkModeBtn />
                  <NotificationBtn />
                  {signedIn? <SignedIn /> : <SignedOutLinks />}
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          :
          <Grid
            container
            direction="row"
            justify="space-around"
            spacing={10}
          >
            <Grid item container xs={4} justify="flex-start">
              <MenuBtn />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item Container xs={4} justify="center" style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
              <Grid item>
                <Logo />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item container xs={4} justify="flex-end">
              <ShoppingCartBtn />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
```